# Passing host environment varibles to Docker compose in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, variables, environment, host

It seems like I've run into a small problem with passing host environment variables down to the docker image when running debug in VS.NET (C#).

The goal is to have an OS environment variable defined on the dev-machine (Windows 10) that is passed through to the application, so that I can read it out using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(string).

The application is run in a docker-container via a docker-compose project.

I probably don't need to explain the exact details around this problem because almost no one seems to run this setup based on the amount of documentation on the web.
So the people who understands the question probably knows the answer right away.

Unfortunately I'm beginning to think that this is isn't possible, either since since the VS support is pretty undocumented or the fact that its inherently the wrong approach.

Hope that someone can shed a light on this issue.
Kind regards
Richard